# Accessing User IDs associated with a Tweet using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

How can I get the information (user IDs) related to the users associated with sharing a tweet (both retweet and tweet) using tweepy? I tried using API.retweeters(id) but it only provides 100 user IDs.